# Synchronous javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I have a script which generates an array of audio files to be played on the click of a button. I am trying to use synchronous JS in order to change the values of some global variables and have been testing for changes with alerts but I get 'undefined' as a result (or my popups do not show).

My code:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
var s;
var group;

var curr_rec;
var curr_start = 1;
var curr_end;
var curr_s_obj;

var recs;
var sync = new Array();
var sync_group = new Array();

var check_rec;
var check_id;
var check_start;
var check_end;
var loaded = 0;

var s_obj;

function compare(a,b){
    if(a.fields.start_time<b.fields.start_time)
        return -1;
    if(a.fields.start_time>b.fields.start_time)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

function process_data(recs){

    for(var i=0;i<recs.length;i++){
        check_rec = recs[i];
        check_id = check_rec.fields.file_ID;
        check_start = check_rec.fields.start_time;
        check_end = check_rec_fields.end_time;

        if((curr_start.getTime() <= check_start.getTime() && check_end.getTime()<= curr_end.getTime()) || 
            (curr_start.getTime()>=check_start.getTime() && curr_start.getTime()<=check_end.getTime()) || 
            (curr_end.getTime()>=check_start.getTime() && curr_end.getTime()<=check_end.getTime())
        )

        {
            //diff = (check_start.getTime() - curr_start.getTime())/1000;
            //check_rec["difference"] = diff;
            sync.push(check_rec);
        }
    }

}

function load_data(sync){

    var diff;
    var last = sync[sync.length-1];

    for(var j=0;j<sync.length-1;j++){
        s_obj = new buzz.sound(sync[i].fields.rec_file);
        sync_group.push(s_obj);
        diff = (last.fields.start_time.getTime() - sync[i].fields.start_time.getTime())/1000;
        if(diff>=0){
            s_obj.setTime(diff);
        }

        else{
            alert("error");
        }

    }

    loaded = 1;

}

function synchronise(id){

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/webapp/playSound:" + id,

        success: function(data){
            curr_rec = eval("(" + data + ")");
            curr_start = curr_rec.fields.start_time;
            curr_end= curr_rec.fields.end_time;
            curr_s_obj = new buzz.sound(curr_rec.fields.rec_file);
    });
    alert("ggo");

    $.ajax(
        type:"GET",
        url:"/webapp/getRecs",

        success: function(data){
            recs = eval("("+ data +")");
            process_data(recs);

        });
    alert(curr_start);
    sync = sync.sort(compare);

    load_data(sync);


    var s1 = new buzz.sound( "../../static/data/second_audio.ogg");
    s = new buzz.sound( "../../static/data/" + id +".ogg"); //curr_rec.fields.rec_file

    /*
    sync_group.push(s);
    s.setTime(20.5);
    sync_group.push(s1);
    */

    group = new buzz.group(sync_group);
}

function playS(id){
    if(loaded==0)
        synchronise(id);
    group.togglePlay();
}

function stopS(){
    group.stop();
}
```

Comment: Did you check for JS errors in the error console or debug console?  Perhaps you script is running into an error and is not aborting.  Also, synchronous ajax is generally a bad idea.  Proper design/implementation can make things work just fine with asynchronous ajax.

Comment: Synchronous AJAX is a contradiction in terms. Synchronous requests will block browser activity, possibly for long periods. You really should rearrange your code to use asynchronous calls, and take steps to avoid using global variables if at all possible.

Comment: I get Uncaught ReferenceError: playS is not defined

Comment: @MikeW So should I pass the values as parameters of functions rather than using global variables?

Comment: Could you help me refactor my code?

Comment: @user3242807 The problem with global variables is that they can conflict with other code that might be using the same variable names. It's not always possible to eliminate them completely, and for now, getting your code working at all is probably the most important thing. I recommend you read about Javascript classes and objects and think about applying that knowledge for version 2.

Comment: Hello, I am stuck with this code. I will welcome any additional ideas on how to make it work.